# Leaflet - choropleth styling geojson polygon data via button click

Tags: ajax, leaflet, geojson, choropleth

1. I'm learning through failure here but still having trouble understanding why my code below isn't styling my geoJSON layer properly nor adding it to my map.

   ```
        lyrNeighbourhoods= new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("data/Neigh_Demo1.geojson",{style: {weight:1, fillOpacity:0.1},
            onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
            layer.bindTooltip(feature.properties.Neigh_Name, {
                direction:"center",
                permanent:true,
                className: 'labelstyle'
            });
            layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.Neigh_Name);
        }
        }).addTo(mymap);


        var lyrNeighbourhoods2020Pop = new L.geoJSON.ajax("data/Neigh_Demo1.geojson");

        var style1 ={
                weight: 2,
                opacity: 1,
                color: 'red',
                dashArray: '3',
                fillOpacity: 0.7,
                fillColor:'red'
        }   

        var geojson = L.geoJSON.ajax(lyrNeighbourhoods2020Pop, {
            style: style1,
        }).addTo(mymap);


        var tooltipThreshold = 13;
        mymap.on('zoomend', function() {
          if (mymap.getZoom() < tooltipThreshold) {
              $(".leaflet-tooltip").css("display","none")
          } else { 
              $(".leaflet-tooltip").css("display","block")

          }
        });



        // ******** Setup Layer Control **********

        objBasemaps={
            "Grey Scale Map": lyrCartoDB,
            "Satellite Aerial": lyrAerial,
        };

        objOverlays={
            "Neighbourhoods": lyrNeighbourhoods,
        };

        ctlLayers=L.control.layers(objBasemaps, objOverlays,{position:'bottomright'}).addTo(mymap);   /* add layer control to bottomright */
   ```

```
          $(document).ready(function() {  
            
            $('#mapid').height(window.innerHeight); //set map height to window
            $('#leftpanel').height(window.innerHeight); // set panel height to window


            $(document).on('click','#btnCustomize',function() {      /* on button click, pull out left panel or close it */
            if($('#leftpanel').hasClass('in')) {
                $('#leftpanel').removeClass('in')
            } else {
                $('#leftpanel').addClass('in')
            }
        });
        });

        $(document).on('click','#btnColor',function() {
            mymap.removeLayer(lyrNeighbourhoods)
            mymap.addLayer(lyrNeighbourhoods2020Pop)
        });
        
        function getColor(prop) {
            return prop > 40355 ? '#800026' :
                   prop > 30277  ? '#BD0026' :
                   prop > 21196  ? '#E31A1C' :
                   prop > 14407  ? '#FC4E2A' :
                   prop > 0  ? '#FD8D3C' :
                                '#FFEDA0';
        }
        
        
        function onEachFeature(feature, layer){
            if(layer instanceof lyrNeighbourhoods2020Pop){ // because markers have not the function .setStyle()
        lyrNeighbourhoods2020Pop.on('mouseover',(e)=>{
           var prop = feature.properties["Total Population 2020"];
           e.target.setStyle({color: getColor(prop)});
        });
       
        layer.on('mouseout',(e)=>{
           geojson.resetStyle(e.target)
        });
    }};
        
    var geojson = L.geoJSON.ajax(lyrNeighbourhoods2020Pop, {
     style: style1,
     onEachFeature: onEachFeature
    }).addTo(mymap);
```

I've been working off of the generic Leaflet-doc Choropleth example but am still getting stuck.

3. Lastly, for my own knowledge, can imported geoJSON files have spaces in the filename or does that create problems? I have been trying to use attributes like: ..feature.properties.Total Population 2020

Apologies if these are overly simple questions. I'm learning quick and usually solve things eventually but after a couple of hours, I call it and reach out.

UPDATE: I've replaced the original code with where i'm currently at. I'm sure my issues are arising from overall script formatting in addition to how i'm structuring my calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. the problem is that your return in the style a function but it only needs a object:

```js
     var lyrNeighbourhoods2020Pop = new L.geoJSON.ajax("data/Neigh_Demo1.geojson");

     var style1 ={
             weight: 2,
             opacity: 1,
             color: 'red',
             dashArray: '3',
             fillOpacity: 0.7,
             fillColor:'red'
     } 


     var geojson = L.geoJSON.ajax(lyrNeighbourhoods2020Pop, {
         style: style1,
     }).addTo(mymap);
```

2. set the style of the layer, i add a `mouseover` listener but you can call this from a button:

```js
     var lyrNeighbourhoods2020Pop = new L.geoJSON.ajax("data/Neigh_Demo1.geojson");

     var style1 ={
             weight: 2,
             opacity: 1,
             color: 'red',
             dashArray: '3',
             fillOpacity: 0.7,
             fillColor:'red'
     } 

     function onEachFeature(feature, layer){
        if(layer instanceof L.Path){ // because markers have not the function .setStyle()
           layer.on('mouseover',(e)=>{
               var prop = feature.properties.colorprop;
               e.target.setStyle({color: getColor(prop)});
           });
           
           layer.on('mouseout',(e)=>{
               geojson.resetStyle(e.target)
           });
     }

     var geojson = L.geoJSON.ajax(lyrNeighbourhoods2020Pop, {
         style: style1,
         onEachFeature: onEachFeature
     }).addTo(mymap);
```

3. I don't recommand to use spaces in names but yes it is working, you can read it out with `feature.properties["Total Population 2020"]`

Comment: Thanks Falke. I tried to implement what you mentioned but i'm still at a dead end. I've updated my current script above. Apologies for the mess.

Comment: @Parkes555 please create a jsfiddle ... your code is a lot more unstructured as before ... why you calling `L.GeoJSON.AJAX` mutliple times with the same data source? And what is exactly not working? all 3 points?

Comment: Okay, I sat down and tried to clean up more of the code before sharing again. I've never used jsfiddle but I did my best to get my code in there as structured as I can separating the html/js/css. Thank you for your patience @Falke Design https://jsfiddle.net/Parkes555/t83zm1k2/28/

Comment: Take a look into this: https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/7dqrsnfa/ This is how I described it in the answer. Please give me a upvate / check the answer if it helped you and/or it works

Comment: Thank you sir! Having the full code in front of me really helped explain how things worked. I managed to replicate your mouse-over event and then adapted it to my button click. One final question as I read this on another thread... would it be better to change the style of a geojson layer based on properties values via a button or smarter to have a separate layer with that style and have the button click "removeLayer" and then "addLayer" with the new style? Right now i'm using the latter for simplicity.

Comment: You can do it over both ways, but my prefered way is to update the style and not use 2 seperate layers. Because it can make problems or make it difficult, when you have to change the position of layers, then you have to update both layers